# Is this swift extension extending the metalview class or the vector?

Tags: swift, metal

In this Swift Metal example I do not understand the concept of extentions and how they are used here. In an effort to understand it can anyone explain to me what is extended in this example?

```
import UIKit
import Metal

extension MetalView {
    private struct Vertex {
        var position: SIMD4<Float>
        var color: SIMD4<Float>
    }
}

...

final class MetalView: UIView {
    private let device: MTLDevice
    private let queue: MTLCommandQueue
    private let vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer
    private let renderPipeline: MTLRenderPipelineState
    private var displayLink: CADisplayLink?

...

        // Setup buffer (non-transient). Coordinates defined in clip space: [-1,+1]
        let vertices = [Vertex(position: [ 0,    0.5, 0, 1], color: [1,0,0,1]),
                        Vertex(position: [-0.5, -0.5, 0, 1], color: [0,1,0,1]),
                        Vertex(position: [ 0.5, -0.5, 0, 1], color: [0,0,1,1]) ]
        let size = vertices.count * MemoryLayout<Vertex>.stride
        self.vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertices, length: size)!

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this swift extension extending the metalview class or the vector?

It is an `extension` of the `MetalView`. It adds a nested struct called `Vertex` to `MetalView`.

In this case, the purpose of the `extension` is not really to "extend the functionality of `MetalView`". We can see this from the fact that the declaration of `MetalView` (the one that says `final class MetalView...`) uses `Vertex`. So whatever is in the `extension` could be considered an integral part of the functionality of `MetalView`, not an extension of its functionality.

The purpose of the `extension` is probably to separate code into "chunks" so that it is easier to read and manage. You probably have come across or written code like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController { ... }

extension MyViewController : UITableViewDelegate {
    // table view delegate methods...
}

extension MyViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    // table view data source methods...
}

extension MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    // text field delegate methods...
}

// ...
```

The methods required by each delegate or datasource is written in their own `extension`. This makes the code very readable. You can clearly see where everything is, instead of just a long list of methods. Are these extension really "extending the functionality"? Could `MyViewController` live without these extensions? Not really. The code wouldn't work if `MyViewController` didn't conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Could you have written all of this all in the `MyViewController` class (or the `MetalView` class in your case)?

```
final class MetalView: UIView {
    private struct Vertex {
        var position: SIMD4<Float>
        var color: SIMD4<Float>
    }
    private let device: MTLDevice
    private let queue: MTLCommandQueue
    private let vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer
    private let renderPipeline: MTLRenderPipelineState
    private var displayLink: CADisplayLink?

...

        // Setup buffer (non-transient). Coordinates defined in clip space: [-1,+1]
        let vertices = [Vertex(position: [ 0,    0.5, 0, 1], color: [1,0,0,1]),
                        Vertex(position: [-0.5, -0.5, 0, 1], color: [0,1,0,1]),
                        Vertex(position: [ 0.5, -0.5, 0, 1], color: [0,0,1,1]) ]
        let size = vertices.count * MemoryLayout<Vertex>.stride
        self.vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertices, length: size)!
```

Yes, but whoever wrote that code chose to use extensions.